# Fix migrate android code error on eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, migrate

[image: Screenshot]

I got an error while i build my app on eclipse

anyone can tell me how can i fix it ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You could also check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Answer (score 0):

**Something wrong with your resources files**

- You must check if there are some mistake in your resources: images or
  xml files in **Drawable** folder or **Value** or **Color** ( RES )
- Or file in RES missing
- Then clean your project

Answer (score 0):

remove switch case ,and use else if  or other whatever you want error resolved.